# Google Maps Platform is suddenly rejecting my request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Suddenly today our services started to have requests rejected by Google Maps Platform. The message we get is the following:

"Google Maps Platform rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address , with referer: "

I've looked into our settings and nothing has changed, all seem to be properly set, including authorized domains.

I've looked to many other questions here on Stackoverflow but none of the answers solved my problem. This integration was working just fine before today.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by enabling the Embed API that was the source of the issue.